# Why am I getting this? Use of undefined constant connection - assumed 'connection'

Tags: php, mysql, constants, undefined, mamp

I am developing on a Mac OSX 10.5 in the MAMP environment. My PHPadmin shows that the database and table exist just fine, however when I try to execute a connection I get this:

NOTICE: Use of undefined constant connection - assumed 'connection'

Here is what I have for code:

*In header before any HTML or white-space*

```
//  1. Create a database connection
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'test', '1234');
if (!connection) {
    die("Database Connection1 Failed: " . mysql_error());
}
//  2. Select a database to use
$db_select = mysql_select_db('widget_corp', $connection);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database Connection2 Failed: " . mysql_error());
}
```

*In the body of HTML markup of the database connection page*

```
//  3. Preform database Query
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM subjects'. $connection);
if (!$result) {
    die("Database Connection3 Failed: " . mysql_error());
}
//  4. Use returned data
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row["menu_name"]." ".$row["position"]."<br />";
}
```

*After the closing HTML tag*

```
//  5. Close connection
mysql_close($connection);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you said `if (!connection)` instead of `if(!$connection)`

Comment: OMG! Thank You! I swear could not see that I had missed it. 
I also see that I need to Change `('SELECT * FROM subjects'. $connection)` to `('SELECT * FROM subjects', $connection)`

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on the previous answer. Basically, older versions of PHP allows you to use strings with no spaces without quoting them. There's an explanation here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar

Cheers!